# ngmodule Module parse error with unexpected character '@'

Tags: angular, webpack, ng-modules

I've gone through the tutorial on https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0, and I'm currently trying to compile the tutorial into a /public/ folder and getting the error...

```
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' You may need an
      appropriate loader to handle this file type. | import {
      HeroSearchComponent } from
      './components/hero-search/hero-search.component'; |  | @NgModule({ |
      imports: [ |     BrowserModule,
```

my webpack.config.js is simple

```
    const path = require('path');

    module.exports = {
      entry: { app: './src/app/app.module.ts' },
      output: { filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../public') },
      module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.ts$/,
            use: [
                //'babel-loader',
            ],
            exclude:[/node_modules/],
        }],
      }
    };
```

and my app.module.ts

```
    import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
    import { InMemoryDataService } from './services/in-memory-data/in-memory-data.service';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

    import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
    import { HeroesComponent } from './components/heroes/heroes.component';
    import { HeroDetailComponent } from './components/hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
    import { MessagesComponent } from './components/messages/messages.component';
    import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
    import { HeroSearchComponent } from './components/hero-search/hero-search.component';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        ...
    })

    export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I've tried using babel-loader and get a Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token with the "@".

My first thoughts are that I'm missing a loader, but I've tried several loaders and babel was the only loader that changed the error message I was getting but didn't resolve the issue.

The application compiles correctly using "ng serve" and they are using webpack with the standard angular-cli application.

I've looked through several other questions with similar issues and most of them are with css or scss and not using the correct loader.  I do believe this is a loader issue but can't find a loader to use that gets it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've finally gotten it to compile and I noticed there were other people having problems with this one so here is the answer I found.

In the webpack.config.js

```
    module.exports = {
      ...
      resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.js', '.ts', '.html' ]
      }
```

and

module: rules:

```
     {
       test: /\.ts$/,
       use: [
         'awesome-typescript-loader',
         'ng-router-loader'
       ],
       exclude:[/node_modules/],
     },
```

Babel might work too, I think the real key was the resolving the extensions.